Realtek 8812ua WiFi Adapter Not Working after installing driver morrownr 8812au-20210820
Installed external WiFi adapter on Ubuntu 24 LTS using Kernel version 6.8.0-49. I have installed the driver from gitHub.com/morrownr/8812au-20210820. The driver installs properly and the adapter shows up in lsusb, but does not show up in lsmod. The adaptor does not light up. I would appreciate help in resolving this issue.
Thanks
